# MySQL order by alphabet - numeric

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to sort Elements in MySQL like this:

Elements:

1. City 1
2. City 2
3. City 10
4. City 1a

When i do the ORDER BY the list looks this way:

1. City 1
2. City 1a
3. City 10
4. City 2

Because all answer did not match to my special problem i edit my question.
There are also Elements with Chars behind the numbers. Watch the example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numeric order when returning results from MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356190/numeric-order-when-returning-results-from-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

I use this and it works well:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(Elements), Elements
```

Comment: This will only work if your database contains *only* elements of the form "City XXXXX".

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that it is not sort by the alphabet any more. If after the number follows a letter like "a", "b" it also doesn't work.

Comment: Correct but in most of the cases I usually face it is functional and quick. With the edit now in the question my answer is wrong and @Devart answer is correct

Answer (score 4):

Try this trick - 'ORDER BY column_name+1', e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM element
ORDER BY column_name+1;
```

Comment: This only appears to work if the value in column_name begins with a number. I.e. if you have '10a City' this would work, but having 'City 10a' would not.  In the latter case, you'd need to split on the space in the value and evaluate only the right half, thus ensuring that you're dealing with a numeric-starting value, before doing the +0 trick.

Comment: Yes, in this case the field values must be parsed, and then ordered, which is not good for performance. Agree about the type conversion - [Mysql picking row when it shoudn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773473/mysql-picking-row-when-it-shoudnt/11773592#11773592).

Answer (score 0):

use mysql cast :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html
in your `order by` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the numeric part of the "City " and order by that.

```
SELECT city
FROM ...
ORDER BY (SUBSTRING(city,6)+0)
```

This grabs the number from "City " (being the 6th character onwards) and converts to a string to order.

Comment: What if the city name is longer or shorter than in this example?

Comment: As in, the city name varies from row-to-row? Then it's a bit harder. Is the number always the last word in the string? (Also, if there are special cases like these you want to allow for, please update your question with them so we can give appropriate answers).